# Add a product attribute to permalink in WooCommerce

Tags: permalinks, woocommerce-offtopic, customization

I have some products with **Color** attribute. how can I have something like this:

http://example.com/shop/category-name/product-title-**color**/

What should I do make this kind of permalink in WooCommerce.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, to append QUERY to permalinks (not base url):

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'my_append_query_string', 10, 4 ); 
function my_append_query_string( $permalink, $post, $leavename, $sample ) { 
    if ( $post->post_type == 'shop' )  {
        if (get_option('permalink_structure')){ 
            $permalink = AddStringToUrl($permalink,'color=red');
        }
    }
    return $permalink;
}

function AddStringToUrl($current_url, $string) {
    return $current_url  
           . ( stripos($current_url, '?') === false ? '?' : '&' ) 
           . $string; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tazo, but I don't want to do this way and line 4 of your code should be `if ( $post->post_type == 'product' )`